# How to input data (numeric values in sequence) in a cell and get as a result these values with an predefined autocompletion group of numbers

Tags: excel, vba, formula, openoffice-calc

How to input data (numeric values in sequence) in a cell and get as a result these values with a predefined autocompletion group of numbers.

For example, I want to save time in typing the following sequence; 120-2020-_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  just want to input whatever numbers it takes to fill the eight spaces as terminal numbers, or instead of just a few of then and completed it with zeros (0).

To illustrate this for example; 120-2020-00002045, meaning that the user in the cell typed as input 2045 then the autocompletion occurs with the rest of the numbers and (-).

Sorry that I'm not putting any code cause just wanted to know if there another way instead of macro to resolve this... maybe with a list, but in any way, all kind of responses will be ok!

Thanks!

Comment: If you want the output in the same cell as the one you typed in, then you'd need a macro.

Comment: Custom format the cell.

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify your tags. You should only tag it [tag:Excel] or [tag:openoffice-calc] but not both. Those are completey different applications and therefore need completely different approaches. Please only tag the one that you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a function similar to the following:

```
Function test01(str01 As String)

test01 = "120-2020-0000" & str01

End Function
```